# Animating an HStack turning into VStack

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I have an HStack consisting of subviews like this:

[image]

Here, the left and right subviews are grayed out copies of the "Day 2" subview, but they're cut off screen by design. I want the user to be able to "reorder" these subviews via drag and drop, but since only one subview is fully visible, I want to animate these subviews to be *vertically* arranged when a drag gesture is initiated. For example, if the user starts dragging the "Day 2" subview, I want all the subviews in the HStack to reorganize and animate such that they're vertically aligned, like this:

[image]

I've achieved the same *outcome* by doing the following:

```
@State isDragging = false 

if isDragging {
   VStack {
      // subviews here
   }
} else {
   HStack {
      //subviews here
   }
}

...

.onDrag(...) // set isDragging to true here with withAnimation
```

However, because of the nature of the if/else I'm using, I do not accomplish the "trickle down" animation that I'm looking for, or any animation at all for that matter. Can anyone give any ideas on how I can restructure this to accomplish this type of animation?

Comment: Could this potentially be done with a custom transition(...) on the VStack?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and after searching for a long time I found you could use `AnyLayout()` in combination with `VStackLayout()` and `HStackLayout()`:

```
let layout = isDragging ? AnyLayout(VStackLayout()) : AnyLayout(HStackLayout())
        
layout { 
    // subviews here
}
```

With `AnyLayout()` the subviews won't be destroyed. So if you change your `isDragging` variable with `withAnimation()`, everything should work fine.